# Using CLGeocoder inside class init()

Tags: swift, class, initialization, clgeocoder

I want to have a `class` that is able to get a country name using `CLGeocoder`. The code below doesn't work probably because variable `country` is assigned to `self.country` before `CLGeocoder` finishes running. What can I do so `self.country` actually gets the country name from `CLGeocoder`?

```
class Place {

    let location: CLLocation
    let country: String

    init(location: CLLocation) {

        self.location = location

        var country = ""

        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { (placemarks, _) in

            country = placemarks![0].country // I removed error and type checks for clarity       

        })

        self.country = country // self.country = "", but should be for example "Canada"

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

all you have to do is move `self.country = country` inside the completion handler.  The data is returned asynchronously, which you can see quite nicely if you set breakpoints on the `country = placeholder` and `self.country` lines

You will need to remember that when you define an instance of `Place` in your main View Controller, the value of `place.country` will not initially be defined.  You can either check it again after a delay to get the updated version, or you can add a delegate so that it updates the parent controller when the value is ready

here's the simple version

```
class Place {

    let location: CLLocation
    var country: String = "Undefined"

    init(location: CLLocation) {

        self.location = location
        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { (placemarks, _) in
            self.country = placemarks![0].country! // I removed error and type checks for clarity       
        })
    }
}
```

and here's the more elegant version with delegates

```
protocol CountryUpdatedDelegate
{
    func countryUpdated(_ country : String)
}

class Place {

    let location: CLLocation
    var country: String = "Undefined"

    var delegate : CountryUpdatedDelegate!

    init(location: CLLocation) {

        self.location = location

        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { (placemarks, _) in
            guard let placeMarks = placemarks as [CLPlacemark]! else {
                return
            }
            self.country = placemarks![0].country! // I removed error and type checks for clarity
            self.delegate.countryUpdated(self.country)
        })
    }
}
```

and then in your ViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CountryUpdatedDelegate {

    let place = Place(location: location!)
    place.delegate = self





func countryUpdated(_ country : String)
{
    print("Country has now been updated \(country)")
}
```

Comment: Didn't work... I get either "Cannot assign to property: 'country' is a 'let' constant." or "'self' captured by a closure before all members were initialized"

Comment: then change the `let` to `var` :-)

Comment: changing let to var gives the second error: "'self' captured by a closure before all members were initialized"

Comment: var country : String = "Currently undefined"

Comment: odd - I have just checked it again, and there was a missing unwrap on placemarks![0].country - updated above

Comment: Here you can see my actual code and the error: http://imgur.com/a/0ENUL

Comment: You define `let coordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D`, but you don't assign a value.  If you change it to `let coordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D? = nil` or to 'let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D()` you should be OK.   The important part of the XCode error message was the second part `before all members were initialized`

Comment: I tried both .. = nil and .. = CLLocationCoordinate2D(), still the same error. http://imgur.com/a/vde0b

Comment: So I tried the second solution with delegates, and it reports the same error.

Comment: In your updated code, you have switched to using `CLLocationCoordinate2D` instead of `CLLocation` as you had originally.  It definitely works as expected with `CLLocation`

Comment: Well, but isn't that weird? Why should it work with CLLocation but not with CLLocationCoordinate2D?